# Creating Hello World from a command prompt, and then show results in Firefox

Tags: command-line, firefox, prompt

I want to make simple and quick programs through the command line and then show results in Firefox...

And I find that Hello World is the simplest way to learn it :)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

As one-liner? **;)**

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body>Hello World</body></html>' > index.html && xdg-open index.html
```

`awk` is also command line, therefore

```
awk '//' <<<'<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body>Hello World</body></html>' > ~/tmp/index.html && xdg-open ~/tmp/index.html
```

**Terrible**, but also possible

```
echo "Hello World" > index.html && xdg-open index.html
```

Comment: Fun fact: the `html`, `head` and `body` tags are optional in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Type `vi` in the console, press `i` and enter HTML code, type `:w index.html` and confirm with Enter, type `:silent !firefox %` and enjoy!